# Тонкий клиент на raspberry pi 3

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi

Господа, нужно реализовать работающую систему с терминальным сервером под убунтой и тонкими клиентами в виде raspberry pi 3 (малинка).

Данную статью на хабре изучил, по сути установил на "сервер" (пока ноутбук) все что тут написано.

https://habrahabr.ru/post/277783/

По сути нужно что бы запускалась малинка, подключалась к серверу и получала свой рабочий стол (ну или хотя бы свой firefox) и таких ~ 20 юзеров.

Если кто-то реализовывал подобное - подскажите что да как?

P.S.

x2go, krdc (с виндой), ssh (с иксами) пробовал - дикие лаги по lan (что очень странно).

Comment: x2go с жепегом почти не лагает. но до рдп далеко.
я бы делал на спайсе, но готового решения пока не встречал

Comment: Пока нашел утешение в wtware, которое для малинок бесплатное:
http://winterminal.com/ru/index.html

Настроило малинку, грузится сразу куда надо. Настраивается буквально в несколько кликов.

Все вроде нормально работает. Из минусов - это винда.
 Под линукс говорят мудохайтесь сами, хотя я думаю если найти более пряморукого чем я, и настройить dhcp и tftp то всё будет ок.

Comment: я делал tftp+nfs для тонкого клиента depo. rdesktop

Comment: Проверяем еще одно решение "Pinet":
http://pinet.org.uk/articles/installation/getting_started.html

Comment: К винде с малины хорошо цепляется через freerdp, несколько месяцев работает такая связка для кассира в магазине. Готовлю вторую пиайку к внедрению.